# Android cursor move to first not populating database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fairly new to Android development, and development as a whole. I have a program that I am trying to troubleshoot. I think I have isolated the issue to the code below:

```
ArrayList<RSSItem> arrayrssitems = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    dataAdapter = new DBAdaptor(this);
    dataAdapter.open();
    mCursor = dataAdapter.getRssItems(dataAdapter
            .getChannelIdFromLink(channelLink));
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            item = new RSSItem();
            item.setId(mCursor.getInt(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_ID)));
            item.setContent(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_CONTENT)));
            item.setDescription(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_DESCRIPTION)));
            item.setImage(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_IMAGE)));
            item.setPubdate(Common.changeFormatDate(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_PUBDATE))));
            item.setLink(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_LINK)));
            item.setRead(Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_READ))));
            item.setTitle(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdaptor.RSSITEM_FIELD_TITLE)));
            arrayrssitems.add(item);
            // do what ever you want here
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
```

The problem is there should be items in the database, but when the code gets to if (mCursor.movetofirst() it just skips right to close, instead of executing the code in the if block.

Is the syntax correct?

And what is the simplest way for me to check the to see if there is content in the sqlite DB?

Here is the getChannel Mathod.

```
public Cursor getChannel(String link){
    return db.query(DBAdaptor.CHANNELS_TABLE, 
            new String[] {
                            CHANNEL_FIELD_ID, 
                            CHANNEL_FIELD_TITLE, 
                            CHANNEL_FIELD_LINK,
                            CHANNEL_FIELD_DESCRIPTION,
                            CHANNEL_FIELD_LASTUPDATED
                         }, 
            CHANNEL_FIELD_LINK + " = '" + link + "'",
            null,null,null,null);
}


public long insertChannel(RSSChannel channel){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CHANNEL_FIELD_TITLE,channel.getTitle());
    values.put(CHANNEL_FIELD_LINK,channel.getLink());
    values.put(CHANNEL_FIELD_DESCRIPTION,channel.getDescription());
    values.put(CHANNEL_FIELD_LASTUPDATED,channel.getLastupdated());
    return db.insert(DBAdaptor.CHANNELS_TABLE, null, values);
}
public
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure your cursor does contain records? Try to print `mCursor.getCount()` and see what value does it return.

Comment: The syntax is ok. Your cursor just doesn't have any rows. Post some relevant query code with data to get help with it.

Comment: I did some further digging, and was able to verify they the getChannel method would return a -1 on the count.

Comment: what does the last part of the db.query `CHANNEL_FIELD_LINK + " = '" + link + "'",null,null,null,null);` do exactly?

Comment: Found out that last row is the where statement. For some reason it wasn't returning anything. I commented it out and add a null to the final line. The which statement wasn't limiting the search any. It was effectively select *.